# Impact of number of DOM nodes in performance

Tags: javascript, ios, performance, dom, ember.js

I have an application which has around 3253 DOM nodes as shown in Chrome. It is supposed to be run on iPhone. How much impact will it have on performance? I did some googling but couldn't find any specific answers.

To be more specific, if I have 6 pages with 500 DOM nodes each, is it better to keep them in DOM and show/hide using CSS/JavaScript or inject them into DOM with JavaScript as and when required. How do I compare performance of injecting a 500 node page into DOM opposed to keeping 6 x 500 nodes in DOM and show/hide them.

Any help / reference / research is much appreciated.

Comment: Try it on an iPhone. Remember to test the particular iPhone/iOS target - *I would imagine it's not the DOM node count itself, but how the DOM is created/manipulated.* (iPhones, even from the start, have been able to run "real webpages", which set them apart from previous mobile devices of similar size.)

Comment: @user2246674 I have performance issues, now wondering what all are causing it.

Comment: First is to isolate the specific environment(s) and action(s) which cause the issues - are events slow? Is scrolling/zooming slow? Are model->view updates slow? Does the performance depend significantly upon loaded resources (images) or CSS? etc.

Comment: @user2246674 That is a good lead, I guess I was just questioning usual suspects instead of investigating :)